# Style on checked text - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a "to do app" and I have a small problem. I'm a beginner with Vue.js and I didn't found any solution. I want to apply a style for checked text and another style for unchecked text. I tried to add index in front of :style but dosen't work. This is my list, with a loop. Every time a user press a button, new task is added in the list.

```
<ul class="list-group task-list">
  <app-image-slider></app-image-slider>
  <li class="list-group-item task-li" v-for="(task, index) in taskList" :key="index.taskList"> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkmark" v-model="toggle" true-value="yes" false-value="no"> 
    <span class="task-line" 
    :style="[toggle === 'no' ? {'text-decoration':'none'} : {'text-decoration':'line-through', 'color':'#718093'}]">
      {{task}} 
     </span>
     <button @click="removeTask(index)" class="remove-button">❌</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Ass you can see, I have that line with :style. This is working, but the style is applied to all the task. I want some style for checked text and another for unchecked text.

And the script tag.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            newTask: "",
            taskList: [ ],
            addTaskText: "Add some task to do!",
            textLength: 0,
            toggle: "no"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        countLetters() {
            this.textLength = this.newTask.length;
        },
        addNewTask() {
            let spaceRemove = this.newTask.replace(/\s/g, "");
            let newTaskWithoutSpace = spaceRemove;

            if (newTaskWithoutSpace.length >= 7) {
                this.taskList.push(this.newTask);
                this.newTask = "";
                this.textLength = 0;
            }
        },
        removeTask(index) {
            this.taskList.splice(index, 1);
        },
    },
    components: {
        appImageSlider: ImageSlider
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `toggle` for each task. The way you use toggle now would apply to all tasks.

So instead of having an array of string for `taskList`, make it an array of objects where each task is something like:

```
{
  toggle: "no",
  description: "Clean room."
}
```

So you will end up with the for loop something in line with:

```
<li class="list-group-item task-li" v-for="(task, index) in taskList" :key="index"> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkmark" v-model="task.toggle" true-value="yes" false-value="no"> 
    <span class="task-line" 
    :style="[task.toggle === 'no' ? {'text-decoration':'none'} : {'text-decoration':'line-through', 'color':'#718093'}]">
      {{task.description}} 
     </span>
     <button @click="removeTask(index)" class="remove-button">❌</button>
</li>
```

Comment: I'm getting this now:  this.taskList.task.push is not a fuciton
taskList: {
                    task: "",
                    toggle: "no"
},

Comment: @Ionuț `taskList` is the array, so you should push to it, e.g. `this.taskList.push({ toggle: "no", description: "Clean room."}`. You need to update your `addNewTask()` code to work on an object instead of just a string.